# Should one put output operations into a destructor?

Tags: c++, class

I've got a class that collects and processes some data during the execution of the program, let's call it `dataCollectionInterface`. When the program terminates (or rather: a `dataCollectionInterface` object goes out of scope) some final processing and output of (some of) the collected data needs to be done.

The question now is: should I put this final processing and output (to files) into the destructor of `dataCollectionInterface` (or call it from within the destructor)? Or should I provide a public member routine (`doFinalProcessing`) that needs to be explicitly called by the main program?

Putting it into the destructor would be a lot more convenient (no need to worry about safeguards against data modulation after a call to `doFinalProcessing` etc.), but are there downsides, e.g. with respect to the handling of possible exceptions from the output operations?

Comment: Your last paragraph is already your answer.  You have the best information to judge what mechanism would fit best.  Find out whether it's possible to handle all exceptions within the destructor, otherwise, go for the other solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be **[throwing any exceptions from the destructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9)**, So better to do it in a public function, rather than the destructor if your operations can throw exceptions and you need to do the exception handling for them.

Though, If you can rather handle all your exceptions within the destrucotr itself without throwing them out from the destructor, then you might go for the first mechanism as well, I see no harm if you can reliably do so.

Comment: Ok, I could have guessed that there's something on the parashift FAQ. Thanks for pointing it out. By handling the exceptions within the destructor itself you mean that I should put `try`-`catch` blocks inside the destructor and write out any related error messages "failure in blabla" etc. directly from within this catch block?

Comment: @janitor048: Yup. But you need to be absolutely sure that no exception escapes your catch handler.

Comment: Just make sure that outputting error messages in the catch block cannot also throw!

Answer (score 3):

A destructor cannot fail.  Thus, you should not put any operations which
might fail (and output can fail) in a destructor; what do you do if it
fails.

There are exceptions, when the operation isn't really relevant to the
overall functionality of the program (logging output, for example), or
when it is a safeguard (`ofstream` will close the file in the
destructor, ignoring any errors), or when it is part of an operation
which will be later "annulled": a non-committed transation may close an
output file, for example, knowing that because the transaction is not
committed, the file will later be deleted.  But they are just that:
exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Others are correct about destructors not throwing, but that shouldn't mean not to do it in a destructor.  Nor should it mean that there should be no diagnostics.  But you definitely should put it in the destructor.

First of all, the reason that you should put it in the destructor is less about immediate convenience but because **zombies are evil**.  Objects that have finished their useful lifetime but still exist to be accidentally encountered and used are the bane of developers.  Young developers come in and touch them when they shouldn't causing all sorts of problems.  Complexity explodes because you now have to check if you've cleaned up things properly.  Exception handling is now not automatic, as it would be in a destructor.  Do you really want to write try/catches everywhere you use the object just because something unrelated might throw and you have to clean it up properly?  Do you want to write "ifs" in all your code for that class to make sure they aren't using a mostly dead object?

Two-phase initialisation or destruction are code smells that you are not using ctors/dtors correctly.  Use them to automate all of your object's lifetime (RAII), and you will never have the code fragility that zombies bring.

So, how do you do it if the output operation might throw?

- Wrap your use of possible throwing calls in a try / catch.
- In the *constructor* of the object, take an optional function callback to an error handling routine from the user.
- In the dtor, when an exception is caught, call the callback (if they gave you one) with whatever diagnostic you can provide
- Wrap the callback call in a try/catch too, as you have no idea what others will do
- Do nothing if the callback throws - they had their chance

It's really that simple.  Don't ever let zombies roam, even if you have special exception-possible code in dtors.  Instead, provide a means to handle that in an abstract manner.  A single special case of cleanup is always better than the combinatorial explosion of special cases when zombies are let free.

Answer (score 1):

I would provide both: destructor with some default behaviour (catching all exceptions and probably silent about possible problems) and a public member routine with extended diagnostics. What approach to use is up to user of the class. Internally the destructor may call the routine with try/catch block, if the routine may throw. The routine should be idempotent (second call should do nothing)